# Turning this hyperlink button into an image hyperlink (Liquid Shopify code)

Tags: image, button, hyperlink, liquid

Bottom line up front: I cant code.

Im trying to edit this code so that the buttons in the code actually appear as images instead of grey buttons. Ive tried AI and that hasnt helped as much as i thought it would.

Heres the Shopify code below:

```
<div class="isolate{% unless section.settings.full_width %} page-width{% endunless %}">
  <div class="rich-text content-container color-{{ section.settings.color_scheme }} gradient{% if section.settings.full_width %} rich-text--full-width content-container--full-width{% endif %} section-{{ section.id }}-padding">
    <div class="rich-text__wrapper rich-text__wrapper--{{ section.settings.desktop_content_position }}{% if section.settings.full_width %} page-width{% endif %}">
      <div class="rich-text__blocks {{ section.settings.content_alignment }}">
        {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
          {%- case block.type -%}
            {%- when 'heading' -%}
              <h2 class="rich-text__heading rte {{ block.settings.heading_size }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                {{ block.settings.heading | replace: 'p>', 'span>' }}
              </h2>
            {%- when 'caption' -%}
              <p class="rich-text__caption {{ block.settings.text_style }} {{ block.settings.text_style }}--{{ block.settings.text_size }}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                {{ block.settings.caption | escape }}
              </p>
            {%- when 'text' -%}
              <div class="rich-text__text rte" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                {{ block.settings.text }}
              </div>
            {%- when 'button' -%}
              <div class="rich-text__buttons{% if block.settings.button_label != blank and block.settings.button_label_2 != blank %} rich-text__buttons--multiple{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
                {%- if block.settings.button_label != blank -%}
                  <a{% if block.settings.button_link == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label | escape }}</a>
                {%- endif -%}
                {%- if block.settings.button_label_2 != blank -%}
                  <a{% if block.settings.button_link_2 == blank %} role="link" aria-disabled="true"{% else %} href="{{ block.settings.button_link_2 }}"{% endif %} class="button{% if block.settings.button_style_secondary_2 %} button--secondary{% else %} button--primary{% endif %}">{{ block.settings.button_label_2 | escape }}</a>
                {%- endif -%}
              </div>
          {%- endcase -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the AI outputs:

```
<div class="image-with-text image-with-text--{{ section.settings.content_layout }} page-width isolate{% if settings.text_boxes_border_thickness > 0 and settings.text_boxes_border_opacity > 0 and settings.media_border_thickness > 0 and settings.media_border_opacity > 0 %} collapse-borders{% endif %}{% unless section.settings.color_scheme == 'background-1' and settings.media_border_thickness > 0 and settings.text_boxes_shadow_opacity == 0 and settings.text_boxes_border_thickness == 0 or settings.text_boxes_border_opacity == 0 %} collapse-corners{% endunless %} section-{{ section.id }}-padding">
  <div class="image-with-text__grid grid grid--gapless grid--1-col grid--{% if section.settings.desktop_image_width == 'medium' %}2-col-tablet{% else %}3-col-tablet{% endif %}{% if section.settings.layout == 'text_first' %} image-with-text__grid--reverse{% endif %}">
    <div class="image-with-text__media-item image-with-text__media-item--{{ section.settings.desktop_image_width }} image-with-text__media-item--{{ section.settings.desktop_content_position }} grid__item">
      <a href="http://www.example.com" class="image-with-text__media image-with-text__
```

Like i said, i cant code id love some help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just replace the code `{{ block.settings.button_label | escape }}` &/or `{{ block.settings.button_label_2 | escape }}` with your image tag(s). To do this correctly you'd add a new theme setting that accepts an image give it an id of something like button_image and replace the label with the image.